# How to test custom hooks in React using JEST, Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I have a Custom Hook like below

```
const useSum = (a = 1, b = 1) => {
  const [sum, setSum] = useState(a + b);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSum(a + b);
  }, [a, b]);

  return sum;
}
```

I am using this in my funcionat component

```
const MyFuncComp = () => {
  const sum = useSum(1, 2);
  return (
   <div>{sum}</div>
  );
}
```

In test case I have it like this

```
describe('Testing MyFuncComp', () => {
  const myFuncComp = mount(<MyFuncComp />);
  it('should have value of sum', () => {

    const expected = '3';
    const received = myFuncComp.find('div').text();
    expect(received).toEqual(expected);    
  });
})
```

It's never executing 'useState' or 'useEffect'. Received value is always 'undefined';

Comment: I don't think your code is wrong. Can you share an working example?

Comment: I you want to test custom hooks, you can use @testing-library/react-hooks

Comment: Issue is, 'useState' and 'useEffect' are not getting executed; and as they are not getting executed, 'sum' is always 'undefined'.

Comment: to me it works fine(passes on code above, fails if I use `const expected = '4';`) with react/react-dom of 16.12 and enzyme of 3.10; may you check versions you use?

Comment: Like I said it looks right. I just coped and pasted, it works as expected: https://repl.it/@tmhao2005/Todo#src/Sum/index.test.tsx. You might have to check your testing env again

Comment: @skyboyer, can you please share your code in snadbox or anywhere else to check?

Comment: What version of enzyme are you using?

Comment: Thank you... I am using ReactJs 16.9.0 and Enzyme 3.10.0. Adapter 1.14.0, Jest 24.1.0

Comment: This works for me on Enzyme 3.11.0, React 16.13.1, Jest 26.6.3

Answer (score 18):

I recommend you to use:  [@testing-library/react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react-hooks)

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';


describe('Testing MyFuncComp', () => {
  it('should have value of sum', () => {
    const myFuncComp = renderHook(() => useSum(1,2));
    const expected = '3';
    const received = myFuncComp.result.current;
    expect(received).toEqual(expected);    
  });
})
```

Also I don't think you need enzyme or any lib to test your component, you can use react-dom and react-dom/test-utils

```
import React from "react";
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import MyFunComp from "./MyFunComp";

let container = null;

describe("Card component", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // setup a DOM element as a render target
    container = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(container);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    // cleanup on exiting
    unmountComponentAtNode(container);
    container.remove();
    container = null;
  });

  it("Should render correctly", async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      render(<MyFunComp />, container);
    });
    const div = container.querySelector("div");
    expect(div).toBeTruthy();
    expect(div.textContent).toBe("123");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have to use 'jest' and 'enzyme' for testing.

Comment: OK, I understand, but you can test your component using react-dom, see my edit :)

Comment: It's my bad that I was not able to make it understandable. Issue is 'useState' and 'useEffect' are not getting executed while testing. There is no issue to get text content of div. Please check my issue in description.

Comment: What version of enzyme and react are you using?

Comment: I understand you problem, my answer is just a recommendation, I will try to reproduce your problem, but I need to know the enzyme and react versions

Comment: Thank you... I am using ReactJs 16.9.0 and Enzyme 3.10.0. Adapter 1.14.0, Jest 24.1.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225221/discussion-between-lissettdm-and-paveloosha).

Comment: Possible error in the first block: I had to use e.g. `myFuncComp.result.current`.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier thanks for pointing that out, I will fix it